# Unable to retrieve email content with Poco library

Tags: c++, email, gmail, poco-libraries

As I was trying to build an email client with Poco library.  I found out that I can't retrieve content with the following method.

```
for ( auto i = messages.begin(); i != messages.begin()+10; ++i )
{
    MessageHeader header;
    session.retrieveHeader((*i).id, header);

    std::cout << "Subject:" << header.get("Subject");
    std::cout << "Content"  << header.get("Content");  
    /// Can't perform the above because there are no "Content:" in the
    /// RFC2822.
}
```

---

```
///example in the RFC 2882
----
From  : John Doe <jdoe@machine(comment).  example>
To    : Mary Smith
__
          <mary@example.net>
Subject     : Saying Hello
Date  : Fri, 21 Nov 1997 09(comment):   55  :  06 -0600
Message-ID  : <1234   @   local(blah)  .machine .example>

This is a message just to say hello.
So, "Hello".
----
```

And also the "Poco/Net/NameValueCollection" which is the parent class of MessageHeader does not provide a method to retrieve the email content.

```
const std::string& NameValueCollection::get(const std::string& name)  
{
    ConstIterator it = _map.find(name);
    if (it != _map.end())
        return it->second;
    else
        throw NotFoundException(name);
}
```

So, my question is: is there any other ways I could retrieve gmail message with the poco library?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on the poco github page. 
the reponse is:

///////////

**Is there any other way I could retrieve gmail message?**

*yes, with MailMessage::getContent()*

///////////

And it did solve my problem.